# Simple http request with basicauth stucks

Tags: flutter, dart, http

I don’t really want to do anything other than a simple HTTP-request with a GET parameter and Basic Auth.

For this, I have written the following small class. However, not much seems to happen here. The request is started but it doesn’t seem to return any result. It runs and runs and should timeout or something like that.

```dart
class HttpService {
  Future<List<Post>> getPosts() async {
    final queryParameters = {
      'data_type': 'temps_today',
    };

    String username = 'user';
    String password = 'password';
    String basicAuth =
        'Basic ' + base64Encode(utf8.encode('$username:$password'));
    print(basicAuth);

    Response res  = await get(Uri.https('mydomain.com', '/gartentemp/api/get_temp_data.php', queryParameters), headers: <String, String>{'authorization': basicAuth}); //stucks here
    print(res.statusCode);
    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      List<dynamic> body = jsonDecode(res.body);

      List<Post> posts = body
          .map(
            (dynamic item) => Post.fromJson(item),
      )
          .toList();

      return posts;
    } else {
      throw "Unable to retrieve posts.";
    }
  }
}
```

In the browser, a JSON file is delivered without any problems.

What's wrong with my try?

Thx niesel

Comment: Have you tried with another site, like `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/`? Have you tried from a pure Dart project on your development machine? Does your browser have a proxy enabled, that your Dart code doesn't know about?

Comment: I solved the prolem with another try:

it's not perfect but is is in progress ;)